# Is this worded correctly?

Tags: grammaticality

The sun and fun pictures never do adequately express the feelings of being there.

Comment: Proof-reading questions need to state the concern **explicitly.** "Is this correct?" is hardly explicit. What is the particular concern? Is it the use of *do*?

Answer (score 1):

Pictures of fun and the sun cannot replace the feeling of being physically present to enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The sentence would make sense if "do" were omitted but I often see or hear "do" used in this way. I believe that its function is to emphasise the verb (express) and its associated adverb (adequately).

Thus, "I do like swimming" is a much stronger statement than  "I like swimming".